# spring custom json message converter for controller

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I would like to configure Custom JSON message converter which extending `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` to work in Specific Controller. I have tried using `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` but that would add it to every end point `/` controller.

Also FYI there are other custom message converters which are configured as `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`.

Comment: You can't (easily). Instead create an instance of your custom class and use it directly in the specific Controller.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify message converters for single Spring Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513590/specify-message-converters-for-single-spring-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your use-case.

### Manual Conversion

As *Sotirios* wrote in his comment, the easiest way is if you marshall and unmarshall your requests manually.

### Configure `ObjectMapper`

You can configure `ObjectMapper` to use different settings based on the class of the object it is (un)marshalling.

### Spring Stuff

You can implement your own `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` and / or `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. These have access to handler method annotations. You can implement your own annotation and pretty much implement any custom conversion behavior.