# Specify message converters for single Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, type-conversion

I'm writing a postback handler library for a service that has some odd JSON mapping practices. I can very easily configure a custom Jackson `ObjectMapper` to handle the mapping, but if I register a Spring MVC message converter with that mapper, it applies the mapping (which is incorrect for the rest of the JSON I'm dealing with) to all incoming requests.

There are a handful of manual approaches I can apply to hand-decode these messages, but it would be much cleaner to have the Spring type-conversion service handle it in the request pipeline.

Is there a feasible way to attach a custom message converter to a specific controller, handler method, or mapping string/template/prefix?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation - I wanted to create custom `@ResponseBody` equivalent that would allow me to configure certain aspects of JSON serialization (in my example, I wanted JSON values optionally html encoded). I ended up creating custom `@JsonResponseBody`annotation which would cause spring mvc to use differently configured Jackson message converter for methods annotated with it.

I had to extend Spring's `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor`to register custom handling for my custom annotation and then I needed to register my `CustomAbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor` with spring framework by adding it to  `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`'s list of handlers. This was also tricky, because if you use xml config you have to do it via `BeanPostProcessor`.

At the time I was attempting this (year ago, Spring 3.1), I didn't find any easier way.