# Configure 2 different MessageConverters for 2 Controllers

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-web

I would like to configure two different `HttpMessageConverters` having the same `MediaType` for two separate controllers. The reason is that there are some external services that uses different JSON formats. We are not able to change them.

Is it possible? Can I create two `WebMvcConfigurerAdapters` and split the traffic somehow? If possible, is it a good practice?

Comment: Is it for a `request` or a `response`?

Comment: The same MC for every request and its response. But for different MCs depending on controller/path.

Comment: I was going to suggest using something along with `@ControllerAdvice` but that would only handle the `response`... :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify message converters for single Spring Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513590/specify-message-converters-for-single-spring-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem by overriding MessageConverter adding possiblity to configure its jaxbcontext and assign supported packages. So, then I can create 2 different MesssageConverters for the same controller and depending on a return class use one or another.

```
public class MoxyMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object> {

  private final JAXBContext jAXBContext;

  private String[] supportedPackages = { ... }; // some defaults

  public MoxyMessageConverter(JAXBContext jAXBContext) {
    this.jAXBContext = jAXBContext;
  }

  public String[] getSupportedPackages() {
    return supportedPackages;
  }

  public void setSupportedPackages(String[] supportedPackages) {
    this.supportedPackages = supportedPackages;
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    String packageName = clazz.getPackage().getName();
    for (String supportedPackage : supportedPackages) {
      if (packageName.startsWith(supportedPackage))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

@Override
  protected Object readInternal(Class<?> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
..
}

 @Override
  protected void writeInternal(Object object, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
.. 
}
}
```

and in the @Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    super.extendMessageConverters(converters);
    MoxyMessageConverter defaultMessageConverter = new MoxyMessageConverter(defaultJAXBContext);
    defaultMessageConverter.setSupportedPackages(new String[] { "xxx.xxx.xxx.webservices" });
    converters.add(0, defaultMessageConverter );

    MoxyMessageConverter payUMessageConverter = new MoxyMessageConverter(payUJAXBContext);
    payUMessageConverter.setSupportedPackages(new String[] { "xxx.xxx.xxx.webservices.payu" });
    converters.add(0, payUMessageConverter);
  }
}
```