# How to configure HttpMessageConverter for specified controller in SpringMvc

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

As we know, we can configure the global HttpMessageConverter by configureMessageConverters method in WebMvcConfigurer.
see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-message-converters
But I want to configure a HttpMessageConverter for specified Controller to override the global configuration to implement the function different from the global.
How should I configure it? Can any friends give me pointers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify message converters for single Spring Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513590/specify-message-converters-for-single-spring-controller)

Answer (score 0):

You can put below code in any of your configuration classes. and you have to autowire this specific objectmapper in that class where you need.Even you can create multiple objectmappers to serve different purposes.

```
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("customForController")
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
          ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
          return mapper;
      }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("customMessageConverter")
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter() {
         MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter httConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
         httConverter.setObjectMapper(getObjectMapper());
         //others configuration goes here 
        return httConverter;

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't express my meaning clearly.I want a way to convert transparently, rather than using it explicitly.
Like the method named addFormatters of WebMvcConfigurer can configure globally the formatter, but I also can configure it for specified controller by using @InitBinder method.